# Highchart : Line Chart not Loading the data from Database on screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I am Trying to make a HighChart's Line Chart Based on the data from the Database.
I Fetched the Data from The Database as I can see that data in the console .

The php Code I Used is :

```
<?php
$query = "
  SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS year, 
       MONTHNAME(created_at) AS month, 
    COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM users
    GROUP BY month ASC ORDER BY created_at ASC
" ;

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) ;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$data1[] = $row['month'];
 $data2[] = $row['count'];
}
?>
```

Now I Fetched the Data in Highchart's script as Follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line',

    },
    title: {
        text: 'Download Trends'
    },
 credits: {
 enabled: false
 },
    xAxis: {
        categories:  ['<?php echo join($data1, "','"); ?>'],

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'No. of Downloads'
        }
    },


  plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                                    borderWidth: 0
                                }
                    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Qty',
        data: ['<?php echo join($data2, "','"); ?>'],
  }]
    });
    });
 </script>
```

I using the container div with id container as follows :

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

The Problem is that the data is not showing in correct Manner . its been showing only half of the data as you can see below : 
[image]

its not showing the Line.
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data serie is made of strings, and Highcharts works with numbers for this kind of graph.

Remove the simple quotes in the data section and it should works :
`data: [<?php echo join($data2, ","); ?>]`